# Unity 3 from NuGet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

I am learning how to implement Di with Unity 3. In the official documentation, there is a piece of text that says:

"Unity booststrapper for ASP.NET MVC NuGet package simplifies this by adding libraries and source code to the project in Visual Studio. The following code sample shows the RegisterTypes method in the UnityConfig class that the NuGet package added to the project..."

I have gotten the Unity 3 from NuGet, but this class was not downloaded to my project. I am using a MVC 4 web project.

Is there anything more I need to do to have this class ?

And finally, how can I create a configuration file, like web.config, to point to, where I can put all my registrations to the container ?

Regards,
Marcelo.

Comment: Unity.Mvc3 is not the same as Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC  which you can get here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/ .  The latter is published by the Unity team.

Answer (score 0):

The `UnityConfig` is a class that you define. Since you are doing this in a MVC4 project probably the easiest thing would be to also load the [Unity.MVC3](http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/) package.

*Unity.MVC3* will create a `Bootstrapper.cs` file for you. What I do is rename Bootstrapper to UnityConfig and move the file into the App_Start folder.

What you'll end up with is

**UnityConfig.cs**

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        container.RegisterType<IFooService, KungFooService>();
        ...

        return container;
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        UnityConfig.Initialise();
        ...
    }
}
```

*Note: There's also a Unity.MVC4 package that works exactly the same way.*

**Edit:**
To clear things up based on comments...

Here are the relevant packages:

1. Unity 3
2. Unity.Mvc (by Microsoft)
3. Unity.Mvc3
4. Unity.Mvc4

My answer is based on Unity.Mvc3 which is functionally equivalent to Unity.Mvc. I find the documentation and finding examples easier with Unity.Mvc3 especially for a beginner though the difference isn't that great. However, I don't use XML configuration, in your case you may find Unity.Mvc easier. There is also the "created by Microsoft" factor which is a big plus for some people.

Unity.Mvc does create a UnityConfig for you so you don't need to rename things as I have above. It also includes an extension to help with XML config loading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jasen. I´d like to get this Unity.MVC4, but I can´t find it. Where is this version ?
And what about using a config file to set up the unity registers, can you show me an example or where I could find some docs about ?

Comment: Hi Jasen... I found it !!! ;) It´s in Nuget but it is beta version. May I use it in commercial projects ?

Comment: Hi Jasen, I´ve gotten the 1.2 version... the 1.3 is Beta... Thanks again. I just wanna know now, how I could use config files to set up the unity registers... I think this is a easy way to update the DI without recompiling the solution.

Comment: @Olivertech Beta software in a commercial product is a business decision you'll have to evaluate for yourself. I don't use XML configuration -- I feel it produces more lines of code -- so I can't really help you there. After searching I have found some official XML config documentation for Unity 2 but not for Unity 3 -- I assume it hasn't changed.